# How to make object spin/rotate constantly in 3d mode outside of animation and game engine

Tags: modeling

Is there anyway to make an object spin/rotate constantly in 3d mode without animation or using the game engine?

Comment: I'm finding this question confusing, it may just be a language problem: do you mean 'without key-frames' by 'without animation'?

Comment: Yes.  The machine I modeled has manual controls using constraints but I hoped to get it to rotate constantly while manipulating the controls for a demonstration.  I'm not familiar with Blender Game so I'm hoping I can avoid using it.

Comment: What do you mean by "in 3d mode"?

Comment: 3d view...is it possible to keyframe and playback one object in a scene and manually transform other objects that are not keyframed in the same scene during the playback?

Answer (score 0):

Shoot, I had no idea or forgot that Blender allows keyframing animation of individual objects while other objects in scene can be manually transformed/manipulated during playback.  No wonder my question was so confusing.  So sorry but thanks for the help.